# What syllable of the Russian surname Орлов is stressed?

Tags: произношение, ударение

Is Орлов stressed on the first or second syllable?

I checked online again and again but didn't arrive at any conclusive answer. Numerous sources state that the second syllable is stressed, but when I listen to their audio examples of their pronunciation, I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

Most bearers of this name put the stress on the final syllable: *Орло́в*. This is in accordance with the etymology of the name, that is the possessive form of the noun *орёл*.

That said, some bearers of common names prefer to stress them differently than the rest. It might have to do with uncommon etymology, perceived euphony, or just a personal preference. Examples include *Ива́нов, Кашки́н, Михалко́в* (and his offspring) etc.

Comment: Some examples of surnames that defy the "etymological" stress: Жу́ков, Бы́ков, Толсто́й, Черны́х.